# Program hangs on Linux and Windows, Seems to work on Mac

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, freeze

I wrote this code for a course.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int numbersToPrint;
    int fibonacci[50] = {0,1};
    int defaultOrCustom;

    printf("Do you want to run the default length of 15 numbers, or do you want to define your own length?\n1.Default\n2.Custom\n");
    scanf("%i", &defaultOrCustom);

    switch (defaultOrCustom){
            case 1:
                for (i = 2; i < 15; i++)
                {
                    fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2];
                    printf("%i, ", fibonacci[i]);
                }
            break;

            case 2:
                printf("How many numbers in the sequence do you want to print?\n");
                scanf("%i\n", &numbersToPrint);
                printf("%i", numbersToPrint);
                for (i = 2; i< numbersToPrint; i++)
                {
                    fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2];
                    printf("%i\n", fibonacci[i]);
                }
            break;

            default:{
                printf("Please choose a valid option:\n");
                main();
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem seems to be that the program hangs in case 2 after the line:

```
printf("%i", numbersToPrint);
```

I have verified this on both Linux and Windows, and have spoken to someone who has tried it on Mac, and he says the code works.

No errors show up however.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: always check the returned value from calls to 'scanf()' to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: what happens when the user, inputs a 0 or 1 or 2 or a negative number or a number greater than 50 for this line: 'scanf("%i\n", &numbersToPrint);'?  What if the use enters 'a'?

Comment: it seems it would be a good idea to always print the first two entries in the fibonacci sequence (0,1) as, for instance when requested to output 15 entries, it will, currently, only output 13 entries.

Comment: suggest not pre-allocating fibonacci[50] but rather wait until the actual count is known.  also, the storage allocation always only needs to be [3], initialized as {0,1,0} then with each number calculation it is the same two inputs to generate the result.  then copy the numbers left in the [3] array to prep for calculating the next number in the sequence.  then, it does not matter how many (positive number (upto about 2gig) that the user requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
scanf("%i\n", &numbersToPrint);
```

to

```
scanf("%i", &numbersToPrint);
```

See [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html) for `scanf` hanging with `'\n'`

Comment: If i left it in, is there any way i can get the code to continue running?